# Unable to Decrypt an encrypted String using Java bouncy castle library

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I have an encrypted String stored in database , I read it from database and then trying to decrypt it using Java crypto.bouncycastle library , Any step that  I am missing in code , kindly help.

```
String encryptedFileContent = "…Ä7ÍYvõÔü ™¢”³0T1¨Naóq" ;
        
 byte[] contentBytes = encryptedFileContent.getBytes();
 InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes);

InputStream plaintextStream = BouncyGPG.decryptAndVerifyStream().withConfig(keyRing).andIgnoreSignatures()
                .fromEncryptedInputStream(bais);
```

It throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: unknown object in stream: 34
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory.nextObject(Unknown Source)
    at name.neuhalfen.projects.crypto.bouncycastle.openpgp.decrypting.DecryptionStreamFactory.nextDecryptedStream(DecryptionStreamFactory.java:128)
    at name.neuhalfen.projects.crypto.bouncycastle.openpgp.decrypting.DecryptionStreamFactory.wrapWithDecryptAndVerify(DecryptionStreamFactory.java:102)
    at name.neuhalfen.projects.crypto.bouncycastle.openpgp.BuildDecryptionInputStreamAPI$ValidationImpl$Builder.fromEncryptedInputStream(BuildDecryptionInputStreamAPI.java:351)
    at com.gr.grid.EncryptionUtil.decryptPGPFile(EncryptionUtil.java:630)
    at com.gr.grid.EncryptionUtil.decryptPGP(EncryptionUtil.java:620)
    at com.gr.grid.EncryptionUtil.main(EncryptionUtil.java:95)
```

Comment: Had you tried to reduce this test by crypting/decrypting the String without the database?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos actually my use case is to decrypt an already saved encrypted string ,which might be read from database or file.If I try to open input stream from an encrypted file and pass direct to this function ,It does work.

Comment: The direct way is working because encrypted data is a) of binary format or b) in Base64/Hex string encoding. Viewing your "encrypted string" it looks like binary data that was represented as string but a string is not the way to use binary data (e.g. think of value hex 0 - this is not printable in a string). To solve your question: Read the encrypted data in binary / byte array form and decrypt them.

Comment: @MichaelFehr can you suggest some matching example to achieve this.

Comment: Read the encrypted data in **binary** form to your variable "contentBytes" and proceed your programm wihout trying to read it as string.